# R: Merge two data frames based on two joining conditions being met

Tags: r, merge, transformation

I have survey data - call it `survey` - where a set of people responded to questions. I have each person's name, the questions they answered, and their response, all in long form (each person's name is repeated dozens of times, once for each question).

Employee Name | Question | Answer

In a second data frame - call it `metaData` -, I have additional data on a subset of the questions

Employee Name | Question | Question Evaluation | Study Plan for Question| etc.

Both data sets share Employee Name and Question columns, which should match exactly.

I need to `merge()` these two data frames, but neither Employee Name nor Question is sufficient to merge on. When you combine Question and Employee Name, that's a unique ID. In pseudo-code, `merge(survey, metaData, where(employeeSurvey == employeeMeta && questionSurvey == questionMeta)`.

Just merging on Employee Name for example would return hundreds of matches, but there should only be one where both Employee Name and Question are equal.

How can I merge based on these two conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to throw them in a vector like

```
survey<-data.frame(name=c("John","John","Jane","Jane"), question=c(1,2,1,2),answer=c("Yes","Yes","Yes", "No"),stringsAsFactors = F)

metaData<-data.frame(first=c("John","John","Jane","Jane"), quest=c(1,2,1,2), age=c("20","20","40", "40"), stringsAsFactors = F)

merge(survey,metaData, by.x=c('name','question'), by.y=c('first','quest'))

  name question answer age
1 Jane        1    Yes  40
2 Jane        2     No  40
3 John        1    Yes  20
4 John        2    Yes  20
```

Comment: Does that imply "both" as opposed to "or"?

Comment: Yes. In the example, I've assumed the field names are different in each data frame.

Comment: The use of the argument 'all.x' = TRUE or 'all.y = TRUE' of the 'merge' function could be useful. This argument conserve the observations in case of no-match.

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar Thank you, I did end up using `all.x = TRUE` for the left join.

Answer (score 0):

Merge with dplyr package

```
survey<-data.frame(name=c("John","John","Jane","Jane"), question=c(1,2,1,2),answer=c("Yes","Yes","Yes", "No"),stringsAsFactors = F)

metaData<-data.frame(first=c("John","John","Jane","Jane"), quest=c(1,2,1,2), age=c("20","20","40", "40"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
left_join(survey, metaData, by = c(name = "first", question = "quest"))

# or using the pipe
survey %>% 
   left_join(metaData, by = c(name = "first", question = "quest"))
```

Also you have other verbs of two tables, with the same logic of sql: inner_join, right_join and full_join.